# Access local site with subdomain on iPhone

Tags: iphone, mobile, ip, localhost

I understand that you can access your computer's local site from a mobile device running on the same network by entering your computer's IP address (with relevant local port) into the address bar. However, I often use subdomains for development. On my local I access subdomains using lvh.me. For example:

```
blog.lvh.me
```

However, this will not work for mobile because lvh.me is redirecting to the IP 127.0.0.1 .

Is there a way to access a subdomain on an IP address? Essentially, doing the same thing as the above code but allowing for a dynamic IP address depending on the IP my computer has at the time?

Comment: no. not unless you set up that subdomain on its own IP. If you're hosting multiple sites on a single IP (so-called "named-based virtual hosts"), your browser cannot sent an HTTP `Host:` header to identify which site you're accessing. An IP is NOT enough to identify a site when multi-site/single-ip hosting is taking place. If this is all local, you can always set up a local-only DNS server, point your phone at it, then you can use whatever hostnames you want.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

So, after continuing research, I found an awesome tool that allows for exactly the above functionality:

**[xip.io](http://xip.io/)**

For example, if my computer has the IP address of `124.4.1.3` and I was running a web server at `blog.lvh.me`, where lvh.me redirects to localhost or `127.0.0.1`, I could access my computer's localhost from another device on the network using `blog.124.4.1.3.xip.io`

I hope that helps someone!

---

Sidenote: The app in question was running on a rails server and the above setup required the following setting to be added to the `environments/development.rb` file:

`config.action_dispatch.tld_length = 5`

As rails was running on port 3000, this also required a url like:

`blog.124.4.1.3.xip.io:3000`

Comment: Just ran into an issue where I can no longer use the route pointing to my localhost setup in my hosts file. Essentially I can no longer access blog.lvh.me via the browser my server is running on as it redirects me to lvh.me. Is it possible to resolve this without commenting out `config.action_dispatch.tld_length = 5`?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not sure. Depending on your use case there are other options. If you have a mac and an iphone you can connect them via USB, which will give you some functionality. I've found the Xcode iOS simulator to be a good backup when the above isn't a feasible option.

Comment: It works! Thank you. P.s. for help with "Get your LAN IP Address in Mac OS X" see: http://osxdaily.com/2010/08/08/lan-ip-address-mac/

Comment: @DuncanWalker It doesn't seem to be working for me. I have a Rails app on localhost with a subdomain. On localhost I can go to `app.mysite.local:3000`, but if I punch in `app.192.168.0.123.xip.io:3000` it doesn't got to the right spot. I get my app's `root_path`, rather than hitting the root for my subdomain.

Comment: **Remember** to start your rails server with `rails s -b 0.0.0.0` in order to bind all interfaces

Comment: xip.io doesn't seem to work for me today. I use sslip.io as an alternative works just the same.